# Create VIEW error Column names in each view or function must be unique

Tags: sql, sql-server

Getting this error

```
Column names in each view or function must be unique. 
Column name 'AuthorID' in view or function 'VBooks' is specified more than once.
```

While trying to create a view

```
CREATE VIEW VBooks
AS
SELECT * FROM tblBOOK as B
INNER JOIN tblAUTHOR as A ON A.AuthorID = B.AuthorID
INNER JOIN tblPUBLISHER as P ON P.PublisherID = B.PublisherID
INNER JOIN tblSHELF as S ON  S.ShelfID = B.ShelfID
```

There's the tables structures

[image: Tables]
The column names are mandatory.

Any help?

Comment: Use the Author ID from one of the tables, not both. You'll need to replace select * with select (column names you want). Or if you want AuthorId from both tables, then name those columns differently.

Comment: The message is pretty clear. Either pick the dupes from one table, or rename them. Select * won't work here, and should probably be avoided anyway

Comment: @TheImpaler Is that valid in SQL Server?

Comment: @EdmCoff I stand corrected. `USING` is not implemented in SQL Server. The OP will need to type the names of the columns one by one, to avoid duplicate names.

Comment: No shortcut here.   AuthorID, PublisherID and ShelfID are all duplicate names.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions writing all the columns needed is the only way, it's a bit long but it works.

Comment: "it's a bit long" you know you can drag all the column names onto the query window from Object Explorer, right? (See the link in my comment in the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to select the necessary columns to avoid the duplicate column names.

```
CREATE VIEW VBooks
AS
SELECT B.*,A.AuthorName,A.AuthorGender,A.AuthorCity,A.AuthorNationality,P.PublisherName,P.PublisherCity,P.PublisherCountry,S.ShelfTitle,S.ShelfCatagory,S.ShelfLocation 
FROM tblBOOK as B
INNER JOIN tblAUTHOR as A ON A.AuthorID = B.AuthorID
INNER JOIN tblPUBLISHER as P ON P.PublisherID = B.PublisherID
INNER JOIN tblSHELF as S ON  S.ShelfID = B.ShelfID
```

Comment: But why `B.*` and not `B.col1, B.col2`? This is just going to cause the same problem when you add another table to the query later, or a different problem when the schema of `tblBook` changes. The lesson should have been [`just don't ever use *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), especially in a view.